# Eureka slow to remove instances

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am doing a POC with Eureka.  When I shut down the service instance, it is currently taking about 3 minutes to no longer show in the Eureka console.  I am presuming (but not confident) this also means this downed instance can still be discovered by clients?

With debugging on, I can see server running the evict task several times before it determines the lease is expired on the instance I shut down.

My settings are client:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.statusPageUrlPath=${management.context-path}/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath=${management.context-path}/health

eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=5

eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
eureka.client.lease.duration=2
eureka.client.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=5

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=DEBUG
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=DEBUG
```

Server:

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=DEBUG
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=DEBUG

eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=false
```

I have also tried these settings on server:

```
eureka.server.response-cache-update-interval-ms: 500
eureka.server.eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 500
```

These seem to increase the checking but do not decrease the time for server to recognize instance is down.

Am I missing a setting?  Is there a best practice to shutting down instances in production to get this instantaneous?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it get marked as DOWN on Eureka?

Comment: How do you shutdown the instances?

Comment: Jeff - no it does not get marked down.  The instance shows as up until it disappears completely.  Patrick - I am running the service instance and Eureka server in Eclipse as a Java application.  I am just stopping the service instance in the IDE

Comment: You can shutdown using rest apis of eureka
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations
For example:

Request URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps Request Method:GET Status Code:200 Remote Address:[::1]:8761

Request URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/v2/apps Request Method:GET Status Code:404 Remote Address:[::1]:8761